# Authenticating Twilio Requests Using Azure AD

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-mvc-5, twilio

I have a web API app in Azure that can only be accessed using Azure Ad Authentication (Not my decision). The problem is that i am using Twilio's service and i have 2 API's (callback and Request URL) that Twilio needs to access to communicate with my application. Is there an example or a way that i can grant Twilio access to those API's. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's possible. Twilio supports Basic and Digest HTTP authentication only, it doesn't look like it can follow an authentication flow and work with a token. You have to expose the part that Twilio connects to with HTTP authentication and avoid AAD calls. Of course if you have AAD enabled on Web Apps (ex WebSites) level and not on your API level, then you're stuck as AAD Auth on WebApps level is currently all or nothing, there are no exceptions.

Comment: Thank you, i just wanted to get a second opinion so that i can be sure. I knew something was up when i couldn't find any resource from Twilio or any other source about Azure Ad Auth.